# Maven how to include third party dependecy

Tags: java, swing, maven, emacs

I've been using Emacs within emacs-eclim for a while. I loved it but there is a issue that I couldn't solve. I have researched for solutions but I didn't make it work.

Here is my question, I have .jar file which is Synthetica(swing theme) I can make it work with eclipse.Just add to external jar and here it is. But with emacs I didn't figure out where to put these dependecies.

What should I do ? Thanks in advance...

Comment: so you are importing this as maven dependency in emacs or ?

Comment: @IsuruGunawardana I have tried system scope but it doens't work ?

Comment: Start using a repository manager upload the artifact there and use it as a usual dependency.